# How does tee differ from redirecting/appending?

Tags: tee

If we want to copy-paste what we just wrote in stdin to stdout, we can use a redirect `>` or append `>>`.

How does `tee` also writing from stdin to stdout different?

Comment: Context of where you saw this is everything.

Comment: I just saw people using tee and didn't understand why. By the answers below, I understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tee` has one input and **two** outputs (hence its name, after the tee component used in plumbing). Redirection using `>` or `>>` has one input and **one** output.

Using `tee`, you redirect stdin **both** to stdout **and** (a second copy) to the file specified as argument to `tee`. Redirection with `>` or `>>` can't do that.

For example if you type:

```
ls -l | tee file-list
```

you get a directory listing on the terminal **and** it is simultaneously copied to the file `file-list`. However if you type

```
ls -l > file-list
```

the directory listing is stored **only** in the file `file-list`, there is no output on the terminal.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Both to stdout and to a file, but why even do that, mere comfortability?

Comment: @kature no. I think you are looking in a specific circumstance where `tee` has another side-effect.

Comment: @kature With some long-running operations that produce a lot of output (which is not uncommon in sysadmin tasks) you may need to watch terminal output in real time (to react if something goes wrong) but also to have it logged in a file to analyze later (or just to have documentation what you did). These are cases when `tee` is useful.

Comment: @raj thanks, that makes sense, maybe you'd like to include that in the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The context of why you are asking this is important.

Example:

```bash
cat one_file > another_file
```

When you do this, `cat` does NOT open `another_file`.  Your shell opens the other file and sets the stdout of `cat` to that [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

This can be problematic if you are trying to write to a file that requires root privileges.  So this will most likely not work.

```
sudo echo 1 > /some/root/owned/file
```

Above the shell tries to open `/some/root/owned/file` before executing `sudo` and does not have permission.

Where as this does work:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /some/root/owned/file
```

That's because `tee` has been run as root and its `tee` that opens the file in this context.  Not the shell

Comment: Thank you Philip, that's an important distinction in your answer. I asked it without context besides understanding what `tee` itself does. Now, via Raj's answer I get the concept and via your answer I have made an important distinction.

Comment: This will work, however: `sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /some/root/owned/file"`

Comment: @raj yes it will.  The `tee` version is commonly seen in tutorials.  But both are valid.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in redirecting output to a file with either `>, >>` or `command | tee -a filename` is that with `tee` you are able to set ***modes*** that can handle errors in different ways and that **tee** can write/append to files and the terminal. Sometimes people use **tee** because they want to see the output of the command in their terminal and also have it saved to a file, `>/>>` cannot do that.

Comment: And by the time I finished typing my answer, there are comments and other answers...glad to try to help at least, lol